# How to have different transition durations for css and angular transition on same element?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-transitions, ng-animate

Given a simple angular ng-repeat list:

```
<ul>
   <li class="fade" ng-repeat="item in list"> {{property}} </li>
</ul>
```

I have a simple css animation for a mouse hover that simply expands the list item over 0.2 seconds.

```
li {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

and a separate angular animation for leave / enter angular transition that fades items out over 1 second when they're removed from the view:

```
.fade {
  transition: 1s linear all;
  -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
}

.fade.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:; 1;
}

.fade.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

My problem is that the original hover animation providing the scale(1.1) that was 0.2seconds is now lasting over 1second because of the fade animation.

How can I reformat my transitions to use separate durations?

**Clarification:**
I would like to separate the hover on/off effects and the leave/enter effects. The hover on/off should both have their own duration of 0.2 seconds and the leave/enter effects should have 1 second. A general answer of how to designate a duration for a specific transformation / transition instead of for all would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6dvsfmv/) I came up with shows that there is a slight trick for CSS OnMouseOut action:

```
li:not( :hover ){ ... }
```

I hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: it looks like this works for the initial hover, but transitioning back to the original state from the hover still gets the longer delay. It will scale quickly, and then scale down slowly, at the same speed as the fade. Is there a way to select hover / unhover ?

Comment: If this is not what you were looking for then I need some clarifications. You want the hoverin to be 0.2s + scale 1->1.1 and the hoverout to be 1s + scale 1.1 ->1.0 ? I am a bit lost what you actually try to achieve here.

Comment: it should take 0.2s for expanding and contracting on hover / mouseleave. It should take 1s to fade away / fade back in when it is removed from and added back into the list. The fiddle you have is 0.2 seconds to expand and 1 second to contract on mouseover/mouseleave

Comment: I have been trying hard for the last hour but cannot come up with anything. This was actually really helpful and got me a bit closer, but still working on it: http://plnkr.co/edit/lNpCnFTgSDODPmf3ZqwN?p=preview Any progress you made?